# Why internet download speed is limited in ubuntu 22.04 and 22.10

Tags: kernel, 22.04, 22.10

I installed Ubuntu 22.10 after 22.04.
In version 22.04 I had an awful experience with the internet connection.
The problem may be caused by the Kernel version used by 22.04, and I had to upgrade the Kernel version from 5.15 to 5.17(there are many recommendations about it in forums). But, I decided to install ubuntu 22.10, which uses kernel 5.19. The problem has remained.
For example, I got OpenJDK through the terminal by 6 kB/s! I even used my mobile internet, but I got the same result. I had to download Eclipse IDE on my mobile and transfer it to my computer to avoid waiting for 23 hours to download! There is nothing left that I have not done.
Please help me!

The things I have done until now :

1. manipulating **/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf** and change wifi.powersave from 3 to 2
2. upgrading the kernel version from 5.15 to 5.19
3. manipulating **/etc/sysctl.conf** and add following commands to the end of file :
   net.core.rmem_default = 32768
   net.core.rmem_max = 32768
   net.core.wmem_default = 32768
   net.core.wmem_max = 32768
   net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 32768 32768
   net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 32768 32768
   net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 32768 32768 32768
   net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1
   net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc = 0
   net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
   net.ipv4.tcp_fack = 1
   net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
   net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
   net.ipv4.tcp_ecn = 0
   net.ipv4.route.flush = 1

[my laptop's specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aKaK.png)

Comment: Download speed is not limited in Ubuntu. You may have some problem with a piece of hardware or some other problem unrelated to the OS. You didn't provide any hardware information. So the question is not answerable.

Comment: It is impossible to help if there is nothing left that you haven't done.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask - 1) Search and research - and tell *in your post* what you **actually** have done, 3) Be specific, 5) Keep an open mind -- without these one can only guess, and that will not allow anyone to find a suitable answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 I added the hardware info. How come it can be related to hardware? What should I look for?

Comment: Are you using a wired or a wireess connection?

Comment: @Pilot6 I have tried both of them.

Comment: Try to boot from a LiveUSB and check the speed. If it is OK, then it is some wrong setting.

Comment: Problem might be upstream. Try a different download mirror, and even a different ISP.